# Percentage difference between two counter objects

Tags: python, counter

I have two counter object like this:

```
A1 = {‘word1’: 7, ‘word2’: 5, ‘word3’: 4}
A2 = {‘word1’: 3, ‘word2’: 2, ‘word3’: 4}
```

I want to compute a percentage difference between the two counters, to obtain something like:

```
R = {‘word1’: -57.1, ‘word2’: -60, ‘word3’: 0}
```

I've tried this solution, but it gives me error

```
R = ((A2 - A1) / A1) * 100 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Counter' and 'Counter'
```

Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: What should be the value for key that is in A1 but not in A2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
from collections import Counter

A1 = Counter({'word1': 7, 'word2': 5, 'word3': 4})
A2 = Counter({'word1': 3, 'word2': 2, 'word3': 4})

res = {key: (A2.get(key, 0) / value - 1) * 100 for key, value in A1.items()}
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
{'word1': -57.14285714285714, 'word2': -60.0, 'word3': 0.0}
```

Another approach is to use the same comprehension but only give the results that are in the intersection of the Counter objects:

```
# A1 with an extra key
A1 = Counter({'word1': 7, 'word2': 5, 'word3': 4, 'word4': 5})
A2 = Counter({'word1': 3, 'word2': 2, 'word3': 4})

res = {key: (A2[key] / value - 1) * 100 for key, value in A1.items() if key in A2}
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
{'word1': -57.14285714285714, 'word2': -60.0, 'word3': 0.0}
```

Note that `A2 - A1`, will indeed subtract the counts, but only keeps results with positive values.

Answer (score 2):

Without the aid of additional module imports:-

```
A1 = {'word1': 7, 'word2': 5, 'word3': 4}
A2 = {'word1': 3, 'word2': 2, 'word3': 4}

r = {}

for k, v in A1.items():
    r[k] = (A2[k] - v) / v * 100

print(r)
```